# Photo Gallery Play and Pause Button

Tags: javascript, gallery, photo, slide, image-gallery

dears friends.

I found this photo gallery ins this site: http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/

I would like to use it but the play and pause button don't get anywhere. The buttons are not working and I don't see any code to make this work.

Is it possible to make this work? Below is the optimized code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/js/novagaleria/slick-bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/js/novagaleria/slick-style.css"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-slick-4">
      <div class="slick-gallery">

        <div class="slick-slider carousel-child" id="child-carousel" data-for=".carousel-parent" data-arrows="true" data-loop="false" data-dots="false" data-swipe="true" data-items="4" data-xs-items="4" data-sm-items="4" data-md-items="4" data-lg-items="5" data-slide-to-scroll="1">

           <div class="slick-item">
             <div class="thumb slick_thumb_rect">
               <div class="thumb__inner"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s1.jpg"/>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="slick-item">
             <div class="thumb slick_thumb_rect">
               <div class="thumb__inner"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s2.jpg"/>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="slick-item">
             <div class="thumb slick_thumb_rect">
               <div class="thumb__inner"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s3.jpg"/>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="slick-item">
             <div class="thumb slick_thumb_rect">
               <div class="thumb__inner"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s4.jpg"/>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="slick-item">
             <div class="thumb slick_thumb_rect">
               <div class="thumb__inner"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s5.jpg"/>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="slick-item">
             <div class="thumb slick_thumb_rect">
               <div class="thumb__inner"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s6.jpg"/>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>

<div class="slick-controls">
    <div class="slick-controls-pause"><a href="" class="slick-play"><span class="fa fa-pause"></span></a></div>
    <div class="slick-controls-play"><a href="" class="slick-play"><span class="fa fa-play"></span></a></div>
</div><br><br>

        <div class="slick-slider carousel-parent" data-arrows="false" data-loop="false" data-dots="false" data-swipe="true" data-items="1" data-child="#child-carousel" data-for="#child-carousel" data-lightgallery="group">
          <div class="item"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s1.jpg" alt="" height="480"/></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s2.jpg" height="480" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s3.jpg" alt="" height="480"/></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s4.jpg" alt="" height="480"/></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s5.jpg" alt="" height="480"/></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/images/s6.jpg" alt="" height="480"/></div>
        </div>

      </div>

</div> <!-- /col-slick-4 -->
    <script src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/js/novagaleria/slick-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/js/novagaleria/slick-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you look in the console you will likely see all the http files are rejected by Chrome. You need to serve them over https

Comment: Can you show us script file for slick? I mean that file where you write settings for slick .

Comment: http://playgallery.siteseguro.ws/js/novagaleria/slick-script.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would have to add some jquery

```js
$('.slick-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    pauseOnDotsHover:false,
    autoplaySpeed:500,
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true
});

$('#pause').click(function() {
    $('.slick-slider').slick('slickPause');
});

$('#play').click(function() {
    $('.slick-slider').slick('slickPlay');
});
```

And then edit your buttons to have an id of pause and play respectively and remove the a tag

```html
<div class="slick-controls">
    <div class="slick-controls-pause slick-play"><span id="pause" class="fa fa-pause"></span></div>
    <div class="slick-controls-play slick-play"><span id="play" class="fa fa-play"></span></div>
</div><br><br>
```

If you want to keep the pointer on hover. Instead of using an a tag. Use `cursor: pointer;` on your  `.slick-play`

Comment: Thanks mendgro however when i put your code the play / pause works but there is an error in the layout of the thumbs, i can't say why this is happening. The smaller photos at the top are large and do not end side by side. Just put what already has an error: $('.slick-slider').slick({
    infinite: true
});

Comment: I believe you'd have to create your first slider as a separate slider (for exapmle name it ```.slider-nav```) and then add ```asNavFor: 'slick-slider'``` to the settings of ```.slider-nav``` and add ```asNavFor: '.slider-nav'``` to the settings of ```.slick-slider```... See documentation and example here: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: That's right, I managed to solve it with your tip. Thank you!